# PSQL Filter query by time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that will count the number of all completed issuances from a specific network. Problem is DB has a lot if issuances, starting from 2019-2020 and it counts all of them while I need the ones since last month (from current time, not some fixed date), IN A PRACTICAL WAY. Examples:

This is the query that counts all, which is about 12k

```
select count(*) 
from issuances_extended 
where network = 'ethereum' 
  and status = 'completed'
```

And this is the query I wrote that counts from a month ago to current time, which is about 100

```
select count(*) 
from issuances_extended 
where network = 'ethereum' 
  and issued_at > now() - interval '1 month' 
  and status = 'completed'
```

But I have a lot to count (1,2,3,4,5 months ago, year to date) and different networks so if I go my way as a solution it's ultimately very inefficient way of solving this. Is there a better way? Seems like this could be done via JS transformers but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You can return different counts as different columns, e.g. `count(*) filter (where issued_at > now() - interval '1 month' ) as last_month_count`

Comment: this works, but I am looking for a way to script retool by parameters so it does the job for me. this way I have to do it all manually, it's inefficient

Comment: Is it inefficient to write the query or inefficient to run the query?  Any competent tool will make it easy to compose that programmatically, you don't have to do it by hand.  Performance questions should be accompanied by `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output or the problem query.

Comment: it is inefficient to run the query I think, as there will be lots of queries to go through when creating the table. that's why I asked if it was possible to do it via JS transformers in retool

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY and DATE_TRUNC.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', issued_at) as month, count(*) as issuances
FROM issuances_extended 
WHERE network = 'ethereum' 
  AND status = 'completed'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', issued_at)
```

[How to Group by Month in PostgreSQL](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-group-by-month-in-postgresql/)

Comment: thank you, this also works but I need a way to use scripts to automatize this. there isn't just issuances for single network, there are other networks and I need the data for not only a month ago but 2, 3, 4 etc.